# How can I change the tick frequency in trackbar to a decimal?

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I am trying to set the trackbar's tick frequency to 0.015625.

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e) {           
    ScrollBar.TickFrequency = 0.015625;
}
```

I am getting an error that says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (Are you missing a cast?)

And:

> Cannot convert method group 'ToDouble' to non-delegate type 'int'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Can someone explain that means or what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I found the  answer to my question.

Demo.Property = (ScrollBar.Value * (Rate));

In my case I used:

Demo.Inches = (ScrollBar.Value * 0.015625);

Comment: You didn't include the code that produced that 2nd error.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for [`TickFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.tickfrequency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for its datatype? Have you looked at [implicit numeric conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) in C#?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right object for `TickFrequency`.  `TickFrequency` of type double is on `Slider`...

Comment: Sorry Henk, there wasn't a second error. I think it was just still three from before I edited the code. Habo, I've look at that stuff, but I am so new that I don't understand a lot of it. At least the  syntax part. @Peter what do you mean about the  slider?

Comment: @PeterRitchie - The variable name is `ScrollBar`, but the event is `trackBar1_Scroll`. I'm guessing the type is `System.Windows.Form.TrackBar`.

Comment: @grapherson I don't know what `ScrollBar` is.  I can't find any classes named `ScrollBar` with a `TickFrequency` member.  There are classes with a `TickFrequency` member like `TrackBar` (int).

Comment: @Peter That is what I titled the trackbar

Comment: @HABO, how do you convert implicitly? At least the syntax.

Comment: There, I just did it. _Implicit_ conversion are freebies that the compiler does on your behalf, e.g. if you add a `byte` to a `short` the compiler will take care of converting the `byte` to `short` rather than throwing up its (virtual) hands. _Explicit_ conversions are needed when the compiler needs your help, e.g. when you try to move a `double` value to an `int` should the value be truncated or rounded? If rounding, whose rules? You have to _explicitly_ add code to perform the desired conversion.

Comment: @grapherson then Henk has the answer.  That property is int

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @HABO but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was designed as an `int`, just like the Min, Max and Value properties.

You will have to calculate your own scaling here. By setting Max to a multiple of 64 for instance.

Comment: So I can't use a decimal at all?

Comment: Correct, you cannot.

Comment: The thing is that I need to set the slider value so that it represents 0 to 2 inches with 128 steps. In order to achieve this wouldn't I need to use decimals?

Comment: Just equate 2 inches with `tb.Maximum=128` and leave the frequency at 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don"t understand how to set that explicitly. I've been looking to try to find examples but maybe because I am inexperienced I can't find how to actually enter that. Can you help? Thanks for helping already. I have the Max set to 128 and the tick frequency set to 1, but equating 2 inches is the part that I do not understand.

Comment: Assuming the Min stays at 0.0` : `decimal distance = (tb.Value * 2M) / tb.Maximum;`

Comment: Thanks. May I ask, what does M stand for?

Comment: The __M__ stands for Money and is used to indicate Decimal.